# lm317 adjustable power supply

Tags: power

Just wanted to check iv not made any mistakes and this should work ?
[image]

Comment: Note 100% sure about it, but I’d rather use one R-C pair (R2 and C3) for each transistor.

Comment: This design lacks OCP and OTP.  Better to add OTP at least and adjustable Current limiter as option.

Comment: What method did you use to calculate the value of R1 to ensure the LM317 is protected from too much current going through it? Have you tried simulating a variable load to see how the system performs with, say, just 4A load; i.e. a little above the LM317's capability?

Comment: If you clamp LM317 to same heat sink as Q's with low R then you may get some OTP.  1~30V not... maybe 2.5~27V

Comment: From looking at the [TI LM317 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf), that output capacitor C7 looks to be a bit large. E.g. their "High-Current Adjustable Regulator" (about 4 A) has just 47 μF, so 220 μF might be more reasonable. Remember that a larger output capacitor will make voltage adjustments slower.

Comment: would i need to heatsink on the lm317 ? dont the two transistors take the current so only the transistors will get hot? should i add another diode to the Q2 transistor? 
 http://oi68.tinypic.com/2vrzfh0.jpg

Comment: Are you *sure* about the value of R1? 30 V across a 1 K resistor will result in a current of 30 mA, which might not be enough for an LM317 to operate properly. And there will be less than 30 V across R1.